# Energy efficient home improvement tax credit

Tags: furnace, heat-pump, energy-efficiency

I have been doing some reading for the tax credits available for furnace and heat pump installations.

https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/home-energy-tax-credits
and
https://www.energystar.gov/productfinder/product/certified-furnaces
https://www.energystar.gov/productfinder/product/certified-central-heat-pumps

Here are a few questions.

1. Does tax credit still apply if I replace my OLD furnace and install a new heat pump?
2. What is. the exact tax credit requirements for heat pumps (I am in Washington state, so I am assuming I will choose the the "North" zone requirements correct?
3. My read is the requirement is as follows (ALL 4 conditions must be met?)
   a. MUST be Energy STAR cold climate certified
   b. MUST have an EER2 >= 9
   c. MUST have SEER2 >= 16
   d. MUST have HSPF2 >= 9.5
   Is this accurate?
4. Is there a website for finding heat pumps with these filter clriterias? The energy star website filter doesn't work very well.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd check the website for the state program managing direct incentives: https://www.energytrust.org/residential/incentives/furnace-and-heat-pump/details